# Remove some text from a column values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column in my table named title_id with some title ids. Each title id is stored like

```
title_1 
title_2
title_3
```

where 1, 2, 3 are the actual ids of the titles. 
I want to remove the " title_ " text from all the records. I have around 5000 records so I can't edit them manually.

How can I do it with a query.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want the resultant number stored as a text string or an integer?

Answer (score 3):

```
Update table_name set `title_id` = REPLACE(`title_id`,'title_','');
```

I didnt' tested it . Please check

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table_name SET title_id = REPLACE(title_id, 'title_','')
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function. You can do something like:

```
UPDATE table
  SET title_id = REPLACE(title_id, 'title_', '');
```

(Ah, and be sure to first test your `UPDATE` query by running a `SELECT` query!)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
update table_name set id=substring(id, from length('title_'))
where id like 'title%';
```

I didn't test this, because I have no MySQL DB available here. The syntax for the substring function is from the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring).

Comment: Yes, at least there's a missing parenthesis. ;)